# Business travel basis accommodation?

Tags: europe, germany, accommodation, business-travel

I am going in a German city (Ulm) from October till December. "As the time frame will only be 3 months – I suggest to find accommodation on a business travel basis."

What does this mean? I have never lived in Germany before. I mean now that I am going to search for accommodation (in immobilienscout for example), what different should I do from when searching for longer-term accommodation?

---

Edit: This is advice from the HR. I am Greek, a European citizen. Purpose is to work on a project there. Budget: as much as it needs. Research: Found the site I mentioned above. Question: Business travel basis accommodation? <- what does it mean?

Comment: Is this a quote from a website or advice from a contact? You may get a better answer if you provide more information eg your nationality, the purpose of your visit, your budget, the research you’ve done up to now and a specific question arising from that

Comment: It's hard to understand, but it sounds like you are being advised to search for corporate apartments rather than a normal rental arrangement.

Comment: @Traveller question updated.

Comment: @Calchas "corporate apartments", yes that's sound correct! So instead of searching the internet for "accommodation in Ulm", I should search for "corporate apartments in Ulm", right? If yes, then I think you should post an answer (I updated my question with further information BTW).

Comment: @gsamaras Have you tried searching ‘letting agencies in Ulm’? Also, I’d confirm the budget with HR before you commit, it’s a rare business these days that doesn’t have an expenses policy governing this type of spend.

Comment: @Traveller don't worry about the budget. No, I haven't. That's why I wanted to ask this question first, in order to search in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: For me, it would mean using the same rules you would apply for regular business travel (I.e. hotels). However for 3 months that does seem a bit expensive, I would opt at least for serviced apartments (also known as “apparthotels”), which are somewhere in between regular hotels and short term lettings, or a short term furnished rental. Of course, they definitely exclude you entering into a long term lease, moving or buying furniture, etc. The specifics will probably vary based on whether you will be there the full time or go back and forth.

Comment: Honestly, the only person that can tell you what they mean by "on a business travel basis" is the person who said this. You can already see this here, where one person says it means "not a hotel" and another person says it means "what you would normally do on a business trip, i.e. a hotel".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The phrase in question** very simply means that you should seek a

- "corporate apartment"
- "long-term holiday accommodation"
- "holiday flat"
- "serviced apartments"

rather than

- a hotel

That's all they mean.

Using something like "homeaway.com" (by far the largest, they bought-out all their competitors), it's very easy to find "long-term rentals".

Comment: *Monteurzimmer* is also a common term for flats for people on a work-party-sleep schedule.